# How to rename multiple files with adb?

Tags: android, adb, rename

I want to rename all files in my `/sdcard/Android/data/com.miui.gallery/files/gallery_disk_cache/small_size` folder to shorter names.
Each file is **65 characters long** and i would like that to be as short as possible, there are +- 9000 files in my folder. The file names contain both letters and numbers.

I have acces to adb debugging with my windows pc and USB-Debugging is turned on
I however cant acces my phone, it is stuck in a bootloop and **turns off after 20 seconds**, touch is only usable to enter my passcode so that i can acces the above named directory.

I have pulled 5GB so far, but cmd is limited to 8000 characters and it would take ages to pull everything without renaming files first

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible with tasker, though I cannot give you the "complete recipe". Basically, you could create a task like this:

```
Execute Command: ls -1 /path/to/your/files, and capture the output into a variable
the command will list all files in the given directory, one file per line
Work on the variable. There are possibilities to convert it into an array, so you can use a for loop to handle each file
again with variables, you can setup the rename command (e.g. using Variable Search Replace) in a new variable. Pseudo-Code: mv "$old_name" "$(s/ /_/,$old_name)"
```

But it is much easier to use a simple shell script in some terminal app (or via adb shell) to achieve the same:

cd /path/to/your/files
for file in $(ls -1); do mv "$file" "$(echo $file|sed 's/ /_/g')"; done

Comment: Your command seems to be doing something, but the file names stay the same. I can however remove characters with:
'for file in * ; do mv -v "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/a//g')" ; done' . But ill have to run it for every character and I have to be carefull not to create double file names this way. I would like to replace the entire 65 characters for each file with just 1, 2, 3, ...9000

Comment: Your command is meant to remove spaces